# How to make GNU sed remove certain characters from a line

Tags: linux, sed

I have a following line;

```
�5=?�@A00165:69:HKJ3YDMXX:1:1101:16812:7341 1:N:0:TCTTAAAG
```

and would like to remove characters, `�5=?�` in front of  `@`. So the desired output looks as follows;

```
@A00165:69:HKJ3YDMXX:1:1101:16812:7341 1:N:0:TCTTAAAG
```

I used gnu sed (v4.8)with a following argument;

```
sed "s/.*@/@/"'
```

but this did not remove `�5=?�` thought it worked in the GNU sed live editor.
At this point,  I really appreciate any help on this.

My system is `3.10.0-1160.71.1.el7.x86_64`

Comment: What about doing the inverse and grepping for something like `@.*`?

Comment: Why use `sed` at all?  Try `cut -b 10-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`, remove everything up to the first occurance of `@`

```
$ sed 's/^[^@]*//' input_file
@A00165:69:HKJ3YDMXX:1:1101:16812:7341 1:N:0:TCTTAAAG
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(\o357\o277\o275)5=\?\1//g' file
```

This removes all occurrences of `�5=?�`.

N.B. To translate the octal strings use `sed -n l file` to display the file as is. The triplets `\357\277\275` can be matched in the LHS of the substitute command by using `\o357\o277\o275`.